# Selecting distinct records using Quarkus PanacheEntity

Tags: java, mysql, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I have a table(MySql) like

```
(ID(primary-key), Name, rootId)
(2, asdf, 1)
(3, sdf, 1)
(12, tew, 4)
(13, erwq, 4)
```

Now I want to select distinct root tsg_ids present in database. In this case It should return 1,4.

I tried

```
List<Entity> entityList = Entity.find(SELECT DISTINCT t.rootId from table t).list().
```

In debug mode, I see entity list contains ("1", "4"). Entity.find() can only be taken into "Entity" object, but what I am getting from select query is String. So, I was not able to convert the Entity object to String object in this case.

Is there a way to get distinct values of a non-primary column using PanacheEntity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using Panache [with Hibernate Reactive](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache) or [with Hibernate ORM](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-projection), but, at the moment, if you want to use Panache, [you have to use a projection](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-projection):

```java
@RegisterForReflection
public class EntityRootIdView {
   public final Long rootId;

   public EntityRootIdView(Long rootId){ 
        this.rootId = rootId;
   }
}

// Panache with Hibernate ORM
List<EntityRootIdView> rootIds = Entity
    .find("SELECT DISTINCT t.rootId from Entity t")
    .project(EntityRootIdView.class)
    .list()

// Panache with Hibernate Reactive
Uni<List<EntityRootIdView>> rootIds = Entity
    .find("SELECT DISTINCT t.rootId from Entity t")
    .project(EntityRootIdView.class)
    .list()
```

Note that [this requires at least Quarkus 2.12.0.Final](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26284)

Alternatively, you can use the Hibernate Reactive session:

```java
Uni<List<Long>> rootIds = Panache.getSession()
    .chain(session -> session
        .createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT t.rootId from Entity t", Long.class)
        .getResultList() )
    );
```

Or, if you are using Hibernate ORM, the entity manager:

```java
List<Long> rootIds = Panache.getEntityManager()
    .createQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT t.rootId from Entity t", Long.class )
    .getResultList();
```

Funny enough, [I've just created an issue to make this easier](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/28844).

Comment: I have tried @RegisterForReflection
class EntityRootIdView {
   String rootId;

   public EntityRootIdView(String rootId){ 
        this.rootId = rootId;
   }
}

// Panache with Hibernate ORM
List<EntityRootIdView> rootIds = Entity
    .find(SELECT DISTINCT t.rootId from Entity t)
    .project(EntityRootIdView.class)
    .list()

But I'm getting illegalArgumentException and "SELECT".

Comment: Are you using Quarkus 1.12 + ?

Comment: I've tested it with one of the quickstarts: https://github.com/DavideD/quarkus-quickstarts/commit/f516d840b7b581d2f743dc8f1e72443c58ab9c44

Comment: I am using 2.4.1. Not sure why it isn't working for me :(

Comment: What's the full error message? It's possible that's a bug, but it's hard to say without looking at the project. If you can create a test case, I will have a look. You can also create an issue on GitHiub: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

Comment: What I tried:
Created @RegisterForReflection RootEntityProjection class.

private final String SELECT_ROOT_QUERY = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rootTsgId from TenantHierarchyEntity t";

List<RootEntityProjection> entityList = TenantHierarchyEntity.find(SELECT_ROOT_QUERY).project(RootEntityProjection.class).list();

Exception: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: SELECT near line 1, column 80 [SELECT new com.xxx.RootEntityProjection (rootTsgId) SELECT DISTINCT t.rootTsgId from com.xxx.TenantHierarchyEntity t]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake before, this requires at least Quarkus 2.12 (and not 1.12). It's not going to work with Quarkus 2.4

Comment: Anyway, you can also try the other solution with `Panache.getEntityManger`

Comment: Thank you so much Davide, changing the quarkus version worked. Except that I need to use same table-column name as attribute in class.